# java Object By Reference

Tags: java

I forgot some java concept.

```
PaymentData payment = basket.getPaymentData(); 
PaymentData newPayment =  payment;
basket.unMaskCreditCardNumbers(payment);
basket.maskCreditCardNumbers(payment);
```

Here issue is when unmask the `payment` object, `newPayment`  object also unmasking. if I mask payment object newPayment object again masking.

Is this happened by "object by reference"?

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java everything is pass by value this means that reference is copied from `payment` to `newPayment` in your case.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Both `payment` and `newPayment` are references/pointing to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is object reference by value.